# Required Attribute does not work on foreign key dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a project using database first approach in which My table

City - has the following columns

```
City_Id
City_Name
State_Id
```

State_Id is a foreign key to state table.

Now all validations and everything is working until I put the [Required] annotation over State_Id in my City.cs model file which is this

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace SS.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    public partial class City
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public City()
        {
            this.Areas = new HashSet<Area>();
        }

        public int City_Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("City Name")]
        [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage = "City Name exceeds limit of 50 characters")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Z][a-z]+",ErrorMessage ="Input Format Incorrect")]
        [Remote("CheckDuplicateInState","Cities",AdditionalFields ="State_Id",ErrorMessage ="There cannot be duplicate city names in same state")]
        public string City_Name { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("State Name")]
        public int State_Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }

        public virtual State State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I put [Required] over State_Id and press the button to Submit in the form in Create view nothing happens, even if I select a correct state from the drop down no post-back happens  or I just select the default display value of "Select State" then also no error is shown.

My view is as follows

```
@model SS.Models.City

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>City</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State_Id,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("State_Id", null,"Select State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And my controller (relevant code) is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SS.Models;

namespace SS.Controllers.Admin
{
    public class CitiesController : Controller
    {
        private SS db = new SSDatabaseEntities();

        // GET: Cities/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.State_Id = new SelectList(db.States, "State_Id", "State_Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Cities/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "City_Id,City_Name,State_Id")] City city)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Cities.Add(city);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(city);
        }



        public JsonResult CheckDuplicateInState(string City_Name,int state_id)
        {
            State st = db.States.Find(state_id);

            if (st.Cities.Any(x => x.City_Name == City_Name))
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

On putting [Required] on State_Id in City.cs the required attribute data-val-required is not generated in the drop down html on viewing page source.

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="State_Id">State Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="State_Id" name="State_Id"><option value="">Select State</option>
<option value="1">Madhya Pradesh</option>
<option value="2">Gujarat</option>
<option value="4">Punjab</option>
<option value="9">Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value="10">Haryana</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="State_Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure... change the name of the ViewBag property where you hold your SelectList of States. There is a small bug if it is the same name as the property binded. So you will need to pass the SelectList in the DropDownList helper.

Comment: The names are same but that's not a bug. The dropdown is populated correctly

Comment: Putting a `[Required]` on `StateId` will make absolutely no difference whatsoever. The property is `int` which is always required (the only reason to add `[Required]` would be to display a specific error message) and if you inspect the html your generating you will see the relevant `data-val-*` attributes are being rendered.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Listen buddy it is making all the difference in the world. On putting the [Required] attribute on the State_Id the data-val-required is not showing up in the drop down html in page source which I have posted above. Moreover please do not down vote genuine and well asked questions on stack overflow which would discourage wanna be developers like me on asking questions

Comment: No its not. There is something else in your code which is causing your issue, but you have posted too much irrelevant code to wade through (what do all those controller methods such as `Delete()` have to do with it?)

Comment: OK I will trim it down

Comment: I see what the issue is now - I'll add an answer shortly - but suggest you trim it down anyway :)

Comment: I have shortened the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `@Html.DropDownList("State_Id", null, ...)` is binding to the `State_Id` which is the `SelectList` property you have added to `ViewBag` (and does not have any validation attributes.

Instead give the property your binding to and the `SelectList` different names so that you can strongly bind to you model property. In the GET method

```
ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(db.States, "State_Id", "State_Name");
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.StateList, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The correct `data-val-required` and `data-val-number` attributes will now be added for client side validation.

then in the POST method, you need to repopulate the `ViewBag` property before you return the view

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(City city)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
    }
    ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(db.States, "State_Id", "State_Name"); // add this
    return View(city);
}
```

Side note: There is no need for the `[Bind]` attribute since your including all properties which is the default (and your including `City_Id` which does not make sense since you don't - and should not - have a control for it.

A better approach would be to use a view model containing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateList` so that you can simply use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State_Id, Model.StateList, ....)`

Comment: I am grateful that you took the time and solved my problem. Thank You so much

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would atleast remove the down vote on my question